# Is one blockchain of one exchange place the same blockchain used in other exchange places?

Tags: blockchain

Sorry if the title is confusing, here is what I mean.

I recently threw some fiats in Kraken and invested in Bitcoin, the first interrogation I had was "Can I see my transaction publicly on the internet if I could find the right block used for it?".
But on a large scale this interrogation translates to "Is each exchange platform implementing their own clone of the Bitcoin specs or is there a general blockchain that rules the entire decentralised financial system?"

Answer (score 2):

As long as your Bitcoins are in Kraken and you haven't withdrawn them, then the Bitcoins aren't actually recorded on the blockchain -- Kraken just has a line in their database saying they owe you a certain number of Bitcoins. You wouldn't find this on the blockchain until you actually initiate a withdrawal of your Bitcoins from Kraken.

Every Bitcoin exchange, and every Bitcoin user in the world, when they do publish to the Bitcoin blockchain, publish to the same blockchain though.